# query behave not as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a query:

```
select count(*) as total
from sheet_record right join
     (select * from sheet_record limit 10) as sr
     on 1=1;
```

If i understood correct  (which i think i did not), right join suppose to return all row from right table in conjunction with left table. it suppose to be at list 10 row. But query returns only 1 row with 1 column 'total' . And it doesn't matter left full inner join it will be, result is the same always.

If i reverse tables and use left join with small modification of query, then it work correct (Modifications have no matter because in  this case i get exactly what i expected to get). But I am interested to find what i actually didn't understand about join and why this query works not as expected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you intend with this query?... The row number, perhaps

Comment: Example: get 10 records from table X (id, name, age) columns. Typical result includes additional column 'total_rows' (which is total number of rows in table X). Important notice: how to make it with right join?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning one column because the `select` contains an aggregation function, turning this into an aggregation query.  The query should be returning 10 times the number of rows in the `sheet_record` table.

Your query is effectively a cross join.  So, if you did:

```
select *
from sheet_record right join
     (select * from sheet_record limit 10) as sr
     on 1=1;
```

You would get 10 rows for each record in `sheet_record`.  Each of those records would have additional columns from one of ten records from the same table.

Comment: I thought that right join will return not less rows then in right table.

Comment: @simar . . . The join does what you expect.  *After that* the query is doing an aggregation.  The join is specifying which rows to use for the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `count(*)` function, without any groupings. This will pretty much will result in retrieving a single row back. Try running your query without the `count()` to see if you get something closer to what you expect.

Comment: looks like i totally don't understand the right join. what i am trying is to get 10 rows from sheet_record table with additional column in which defined total records in sheet_record table.  I did try to run without count and as expected 21000 record to multiply and in all cases condition is true(will take to long and not what expected)

Comment: You may need to use a foreign key to join on. Without joining on certain columns, each column will match with each other column from the other table.
[Right Join Example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) You can notice the use of "ON" in the examples. If you provide the column names of these two tables, we can help you with the query.

Comment: it does not matter column names. Query is just about to get limit amount of row from any table with additional column with a total number of rows in this table. This is common problem to show table in ui with ability of paging. I did find query which can do this, with left join. I was just testing to make query with same result using right join.

Comment: I see. The right table you are joining with has 10 rows. The left table does not specify the row limit. So when you do a right join, it will take the 10 rows and match then with the left table if there is a match. This will result in 10 **or more** rows returned. To limit the rows returned to 10, you can use a specific match to only get 1 match per row. Also, you can move your 'limit 10' to the very end of your query, instead of being inside parenthesis and that should limit the returned rows to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually with help of commentators I did understood what was wrong. Not wrong actually, but what exactly i was not catching.

```
// this code below is work fine. query will return page 15 with 10 records in.

select *from sheet_record inner join (select count(*) as total from sheet_record) as sr on 1=1 limit 10 offset 140;
```

I was thinking that join takes table from left and join with the right table. But the moment i was working on script(above) I had on right side a view(table built by subquery) instead of pure table and i was thinking that left side as well a view, made by (select * from sheet_record) which is a mistake.

Idea is to get set of records from table X with additional column having value of total number of records in table.
(This is common problem when there is a demand to show table in UI using paging. To know how many pages still should be available i need to know how many record in total so i can calculate how many pages still available)

I think it should be something

```
select * from (
    (here is some subquery which will give a view using count(*) function on some table X and it will be used as left table) 
    right join 
    (here is some subquery which will get some set or records from table X with limit and offset)
    on 1=1 //becouse i need all row from right table(view) in all cases it should be true
)
```

Query with right join will a bit complicated.
I am using postgres.

So eventually i managed to get result with right join

```
select * from (select count(*) as total from sheet_record) as srt right join (select * from sheet_record limit 10 offset 140) as sr on 1=1;
```